# Microsoft Outlook not receiving emails from my address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Many clients using Microsoft Email services cannot receive emails from my Microsoft-provided work email address. I tested by sending myself an email to a personal Outlook address, and the email didn't appear in Inbox nor Junk, however searching for it finally revealed the email (although I don't know which mailbox it's in). When I sent myself an email to a Gmail personal account, I had no problems and it instantly appeared in inbox and I got a notification and everything.

What could be the problem? How can I make sure even people using Outlook will get notifications for my emails and have them appear in Inbox?

Comment: There's really no way for this to be troubleshot, other than through your work IT department or Microsoft directly, since you don't have control over the email server or its service _(there's likely little that can be done on the user end since it sounds like a configuration issue)_.

Comment: Are you working with Outlook desktop client? If so, we could hover over the search result, so that it could display the folder path of the message.  Also, in order to further confirm if the issue is related to your account or client, it's recommended to test on your web mail to check if it has any differences there.